# understanding inverse complex log in $e^z=-2$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I can see $z = ln(2)+i\pi(2k+1)$, but I can't grasp how to get there using the formula for $e^z=w$, $z =  log(w) + 2ik\pi$ as $log(-2)$ doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write -2 in its polar form which is $2e^{i \pi}$.
You get $e^z = 2e^{i \pi}$. Then apply the formula you mentioned.